# Can't cast superclass to subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm currently writing an abstraction layer between my game and the rendering engine. Unfortunately, I came accross a problem: I just can't seem to cast a superclass (The abstract interface) to a subclass (The implementation for a concrete engine). Here is my code:

IInitationSettings.h

```
class IInitationSettings {};
```

OxygineInitiationSettings.h

```
#include "IInitiationSettings.h"
#include "core/oxygine.h"
class OxygineInitiationSettings : public IInitationSettings, public oxygine::core::init_desc {
public:
    OxygineInitiationSettings(const char* title, bool vsync, bool fullscreen, int width, int height);
};
```

OxygineInitiationSettings.cpp

```
#include "OxygineInitiationSettings.h"
OxygineInitiationSettings::OxygineInitiationSettings(const char* title, bool vsync, bool fullscreen, int width, int height) : oxygine::core::init_desc() {
    this->title = title;
    this->vsync = vsync;
    this->fullscreen = fullscreen;
    this->w = width;
    this->h = height;
}
```

The abstract init method:

```
static void init(IInitiationSettings& initSettings);
void GraphicsFactory::init(IInitiationSettings& initSettings){
#ifdef USE_OXYGINE_RENDERING
    OxygineInitiationSettings settings = initSettings; //Does not work
    oxygine::core::init_desc desc = initSettings; // Does not work
    oxygine::core::init((oxygine::core::init_desc)((OxygineInitiationSettings)initSettings)); //Does not work
#endif
}
```

How do I cast my abstract interface to the concrete implementation? I want to add a newInitiationSettings-Method too, which will return an IInitiationSettings Object which I will pass into the init method, in order to have a clean code.
(I want my ingame-code look like this:

```
GraphicsFactory::init(GraphicsFactory::newInitiationSettings(args));
```

)

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. How to do [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) or dynamic cast? How to avoid the need to cast?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Could you provide some error messages?

Comment: @AmiTavory Nah, I'm asking why I can't cast my superclass IInitationSettings to my subclass OxygineInitationSettings

Comment: @MateuszKacprzak  Well, just IntelliJ telling me that the casts I'm doing are impossible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fundamental mistake here is an attempt to cast the object itself to a different type in your abstract init method. Casting upward (i.e. towards the base class) results in [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274634/89999), as it makes a copy of just the base class's data. That's typically bad, but casting downward is potentially impossible. So the compiler won't let you.

What you really want to do is work at the reference or pointer level. Speaking loosely, a reference is syntactic sugar for a pointer, and a pointer to an object is substitutable for a pointer to one of its base classes. That's why you could pass a `derived` through a parameter of type `base&`. But when you try to get your `derived` back, you have to ask for a `derived&` or a `derived*`. In your case this looks more like one of these:

```
static_cast<OxygineInitiationSettings&>(initSettings) // or
dynamic_cast<OxygineInitiationSettings&>(initSettings)
```

or, if you need a pointer, perhaps this:

```
static_cast<OxygineInitiationSettings*>(&initSettings) // or
dynamic_cast<OxygineInitiationSettings*>(&initSettings)
```

If you know for certain that `initSettings` will refer to an `OxygineInitiationSettings` instance, you can and should use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`. If you aren't certain, you should either become certain or use `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`. Note that the dynamic reference cast will raise a `std::bad_cast` exception, and the dynamic pointer cast will return a null pointer if the actual object referenced by `initSettings` isn't actually an `OxygineInitiationSettings`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; But unfortunately, it does not work. IntelliJ underlines static_cast and says "Invalid typeconversion"

Comment: Nevermind, it works, I mistyped "Initiation" in the header class =)

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/#dynamic_cast) can be performed from virtual class, that is class which have virtual methods. Simply adding *dummy()* method like that:

```
class IInitationSettings {
    virtual void dummy() {}
};
```

and changing from implicit to dynamic cast:

```
void GraphicsFactory::init(IInitationSettings& initSettings) {
    OxygineInitiationSettings settings =
        dynamic_cast<OxygineInitiationSettings&>(initSettings); //Does indeed work
}
```

would resolve problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But why do I need to add a dummy method to tell the compiler that the class is abstract? Meh, I liked Java interfaces & abstract-classes more...

Comment: It is semantically incorrect to not have a virtual destructor on the base class if you delete (manually or using any smart pointer wrapper) when type is a base class. So, no you don't need a dummy method. Use a virtual destructor instead; it's probably what you really want.